# Do values passed into a function update outside the function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm working in Matlab on using blockproc to process through an image and use NNMF to decompose it into two factor matrices. My question is that if I pass a variable into a function and modify it does this value modify outside the function

eg

```
function R = addOne (value, value2)
   value2 = value2 + 1;
   R = value + 1;
end
```

For example if I call the function above only value+1 will be passed back as the return. If i access the variable I passed in as value2 will it also have increased?

I ask this because blockproc only allows 1 matrix to be returned but I will need to modify two matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, Matlab passes variables *by value*, and not *by reference* (see also [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-15SO4/index.html?solution=1-15SO4)). This means that a variable passed into a function is basically an independent copy of the variable in the original workspace. Note that [handle objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brfylwk-1.html) are an exception, but they won't solve your issue.

To solve your problem, you could catenate the two outputs along the third dimension, so that the first plane of the output `out(:,:,1)` corresponds to the first factor matrix, and the second plane of the output `out(:,:,2)` corresponds to the second factor matrix.